# Enum issues in Rails 7.1.2 and Ruby 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

```
enum :status_ids, {
 pending: 0,
 verified: 1,
 work_in_progress: 2,
 complete: 3
}

enum :type_ids, {
 price_variance: 0,
 oos_in_store: 1,
 not_in_store_file: 2,
 not_in_master_db: 3,
 data_not_correct: 4
 }
```

These are my enums but i'm facing this error:

`` declared attribute type for enum 'status_ids'. Enums must be backed by a database column or declared with an explicit type via `attribute`. (RuntimeError) ``

I have tried `attr_accessor`, explicitly called `status_ids` and `type_ids` with attribute

I also don't want to use database columns as well

A permanent solution of enum in rails 7.1.2

Comment: _"I have tried `attr_accessor`"_ – try `attribute` as mentioned in the error message, i.e. `attribute :status_ids, :type_id`. Also make sure to call it before calling `enum`.

Comment: @Stefan i have done this but still facing same error:

`attribute :status_ids
  attribute :type_ids
  enum :status_ids, {
    pending: 0,
    verified: 1,
    work_in_progress: 2,
    complete: 3
  }

  enum :type_ids, {
    price_variance: 0,
    oos_in_store: 1,
    not_in_store_file: 2,
    not_in_master_db: 3,
    data_not_correct: 4
  }`

Comment: My bad, [`attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) can't be called with multiple names, it expects a _type_ as the 2nd argument. The [7.1.2 changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.2/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-712-november-10-2023) example uses "string", so `attribute :status_ids, :string` / `attribute :type_ids, :string` might actually work.

Comment: @Stefan
`An error occurred when inspecting the object: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:"PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column product_proposals.status_ids does not exist\nLINE 1: ...oduct_proposals\".* FROM \"product_proposals\" WHERE \"product_p...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"product_proposals.status_id\".\n">`

now this error comes up

Comment: When does that error come up?

Comment: I am using active admin basically, and i have a model of Product Proposal
when i open it in my active admin or i check in rails c using this command:`ProductProposal.pending` then this error comes up

Comment: What about `ProductProposal.new` or `ProductProposal.first` – does that work?

Comment: Yes both commands are working fine @Stefan

Comment: The (new) error says _"product_proposals.status_ids does not exist"_. Seems like you are including that value in your query although it doesn't exist as a database column. You might want to update your question with additional data like your scope definition and that error (or maybe post a new question regarding the scope issue)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the solution , explicitly defining variables in my model works fine. Can you please tell me what is impact of adding attributes explicitly in our project and also can you provide me documentation regarding explicitly defined attributes

Comment: I've posted a link to the docs in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77824265/enum-issues-in-rails-7-1-2-and-ruby-3-2-1?noredirect=1#comment137198957_77824265). Regarding the impact: I'm not sure what you mean by that. In order to get `enum` working you need a database column or an attribute. Otherwise, you cannot use ActiveRecord's `enum` method.

Answer (score 0):

Without a database column, you have to define an attribute with the same name via the [`attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) method. According to the [7.1.2 changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.2/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-712-november-10-2023) example, the attribute has to be of type `:string`:

> Re-enable support for using enum with non-column-backed attributes. Non-column-backed attributes must be previously declared with an explicit type. For example:
>
> ```rb
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>   attribute :topic, :string
>   enum topic: %i[science tech engineering math]
> end
> ```

Applied to your code:

```
attribute :status_ids, :string
attribute :type_ids, :string

enum status_ids: { ... }
enum type_ids: { ... }
```

Note that without a corresponding column in your database, those attributes won't be persisted and likewise aren't available for database queries.