# Enum error in Rails 7.1.2 with Postgres Undefined column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, pg

An error occurred when inspecting the object:

```
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:"PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column product_proposals.status_ids does not exist\nLINE 1: ...oduct_proposals\".* FROM \"product_proposals\" WHERE \"product_p...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"product_proposals.status_id\".\n">'
```

This the method i am using:

```
attribute :status_ids, :string
  attribute :type_ids, :string
 
  enum :status_ids, [
    pending: 0,
    verified: 1,
    work_in_progress: 2,
    complete: 3
]

  enum :type_ids, {
    price_variance: 0,
    oos_in_store: 1,
    not_in_store_file: 2,
    not_in_master_db: 3,
    data_not_correct: 4
  }
```

I have explicitly defined the attributes because this error was showing up:

```
Undeclared attribute type for enum 'type_ids'. Enums must be backed by a database column or declared with an explicit type via `attribute`. (RuntimeError)
```

I want a permanent fix for this

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to store those status and type values into the database? How do you plan to use those attributes when they are not persisted and reset when the record is loaded from the database?

Comment: Please include the Rails query / scope that causes the error.

Comment: Have a look at the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), your question is hard to read without proper formatting. (you can create [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) by indenting code with 4 spaces or by wrapping it in 3 backticks)

Comment: I agree with @spickermann it appears that you are trying to query based on `product_proposals.status_ids` but since that is not a database column the query fails. Please post the failing code but also know that if you want to query based on this you will need to store it in the database (as explained on the previous post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77825547/1978251))